# Organising data for a football (soccer) management simulation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create an online football (soccer) management game with Ruby on Rails, and as it's quite ambitious for me I'm finding some parts fairly challenging. I've coded a basic match engine, but when it comes to tactics, lineups, formations, etc. I'm finding it more difficult to organise the various data and create relations in ActiveRecord. The same applies to league and cup systems.

I'll try to provide a brief overview here:

- a nation/club has a first team and a youth/u21 team
- a nation/club/team has players
- a nation/club/team has matches against others in league and cup systems
- a league system has three leagues in each division (pyramid system: 1 promoted, 3 relegated)
- a cup system has knockout matches (and occasionally mini-league group stages) including extra time and penalty shootouts
- a league/cup has rounds/match days for each season
- a round/match day has matches
- a match has details e.g. scores/ratings
- a match has actions e.g. goal/assist
- a match has tactics/lineups for each team e.g. formation/players

Any ideas how best to organise this in models?

**Edit**: What I'm mainly having trouble with is linking players to matches (via lineups?). Both teams need 11 of their players selected to play: 1 in goal and the remaining 10 outfield players spread across the defence/midfield/attack outfield positions, e.g. 4-4-2, etc. So Player 11 could be chosen to play in midfield, Player 9 in attack, Player 1 in goal, etc. Possible formations include 3-5-2, 3-4-3, 4-4-2, 4-5-1, 4-3-3, etc.

Here's a sample of the schema I'm attempting to use:

```
create_table "teams", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "nation_id"
  ...
end

create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "nation_id"
  t.integer  "team_id"
  ...
end

create_table "matches", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "home_team_id"
  t.integer  "away_team_id"
  ...
end

create_table "lineups", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "match_id"
  t.integer  "team_id"
  ...
end

create_table "formations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  ...
end

create_table "positions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "formation_id"
  t.string   "name"
  ...
end
```

Would something like this work? I'm not sure if the formations or positions tables are neccessary, or if that would even work.

Comment: This seems too broad for this format--I don't think SO is meant to be a place where someone can design your data model for you.  Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new and didn't know how specific I could be; I didn't want someone else to do all the work for me :) I've added some of my code if that's okay.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a Rails question per se - it is a general modelling question. There should be a large number of books, articles and tutorials on objectoriented modelling out there.

Without going into much detail here:

- Basically, you also did most of the work by writing out your list.
- Every word that is a substantive in your description leads to a (candidate for a) model. I.e.: nation, club, team, player, match, league-system, cup, league, division, match-day etc.
- Draw those in boxes (google "UML class diagram" if you want to do it fancy). Those boxes correspond to files `app/models/*.rb`.
- Draw a line between each of the boxes that have some kind of relationship (a.k.a., association) between them.
- Mark out how many of each can be related (i.e., "each player can have zero or one team", "each team can have many players" etc.). This gives you to your `has_many`, `has_one` and `belongs_to` associations.

At the end, look for models that are just too trivial to have their actual Rails class. For example, the "day" might or might not be class-worthy (i.e., it could simply be a date attribute for your matches; but if you want to associate more information with the day per se, or if you want to plan matches which occur on the same day without having an actual date yet during the planning phase, then go ahead). Much of this is a matter of style, opinion and experience, there are no hard and fast rules here.

Check out the classical work "Design Patterns" for *the* introduction into modelling.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I was hoping the list might help. I think my main problem is working out how to plan the formations and lineups, e.g. 4-4-2 has defenders/midfielders/attackers in each position, so I need to figure out a good way of storing the data in the model.

Comment: Well, things like this are were the "style, opinion and experience" part come in. If I am unsure, I start out with every substantive being a class, period. So you have a class `Formation` (storing the general formation archetype, probably with a name and three number attributes "defender_count", "midfielder_count", "attacker_count"), a relationship class `Lineup` which basically links `Formation` and `Match` and `Team` ("this team uses this formation in this particular match"). If, then, you find that you overmodelled, then you remove classes and replace them by attributes elsewhere.

Comment: I wonder how I could link the players into it, e.g. Player 3 in defence, Player 7 in midfield, etc. It's mainly the attributes I'm trying to get my head around (what to name and relate them in which models).

Comment: I did something similar using the NBA though I haven't worked out set ups since it's very difference, but if you really want to be able to break down specific lineups you'll have to have a line up table.  The line up table would be linked to the 'participant' table - each 'game' has two participants.  My understanding of futbol is a bit lacking but you could give a player id and then position (back, middle, forward) id I think?  The more detail you want to be able to play with the more granular your tables need to be (and if you want any help, I love normalizing data)

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the post to show some of the schema, hopefully that helps. Basically, a 4-4-2 formation has 1 goalkeeper, 4 defenders, 4 midfielders and 2 forwards, so 11 players need to be linked in total for each team's lineup. For 4-3-3, 3-5-2, etc. I have varying amounts of players in each position, but still 11 in total (including the 'keeper).